# List of key value pairs to array of arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

have something like the following:

```
var obj = {1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6}
```

Need something like the following:

```
var ar = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

I've tried a few things including the following:

```
var objToAr = $.map(obj, function(key, value) {

    return [key, value];

});

// objToAr = [2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5]
```

Using jQuery, what is the most efficient way to accomplish this using jQuery?

Comment: `var obj = {
    1: 2,
    3: 4,
    5: 6
};

var objToAr = Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) {
    return [+key, obj[key]];
});
console.log(objToAr);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) with [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
var obj = {1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6},
    arr = Object.keys(obj).map(function (k) { return [+k, obj[k]]; });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arr, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [];
for (i in obj){ a.push([i, obj[i]]); }
```

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
var obj = {1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6};

function conv(obj){

  var rslt = [];

  for (var key in obj) {
   if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
     rslt.push([key, obj[key]]);
   }      
  }
 return rslt;
}

var ar = conv(obj);
```